# CQRS Design Pattern

Tags: database, microservices, cqrs

Apologies if there are existing threads that I miss. Please point me to right one.

I designed a system using cqrs and into different microservices.
Example:
A1,B1 microservices -> commands, different business operation.
C1 -> query just for reading aggregated data from read db

Question, should reading be part of A1 and B1 in order not to create a single point of failure? But then it seems 1 microservice is doing both c and q, is that right way?

My database is split for reading and writing. Reading is nosql

Comment: A1 can only provide information about A1. If you need aggregated information, you need to read from C1. Now, C1 can have redundancy on its own, if you are concerned about a single point of failure; the replication delay can be configured as almost online (more expensive), a few minutes delayed (15 mins typically), hours, or a whole day. If you look at Aurora, for example, it has one write instance, and 6 read-only (replicates) instances.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for commenting. So the idea is to still have the read at C1 and not have read in A1 or B1. Understood.

Comment: Typically A1 and B1 will be dedicated to produce transactional changes, and to execute simple non-aggregated queries. The goal of C1 is to consolidate data and execute complex queries **without impacting performance** in A1 and B1.